# C# - from time to time check if a file exists and read from it

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, windows-services

I creating an windows service which will from time to time check if a certain exists and if it does, then reads from it, sends data to a server and move a file to another folder. A file's size is about 1-3 Mb.

I think I will use `System.Threading.Timer` here to check if a file exists. What do you think of it?

And another question. If a file is being copied then my app must not read from it. It should wait until copying is done. Only after that it must read from it and does other activities.

So the questions:

1) Is that a right decision to use `System.Threading.Timer`?

2) How do I check a file is being copied and wait until it's done?

3) Must I use multi-threading?

Comment: Try to stick to one, well-defined question per post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach I've used is to monitor the folder/s with FileSystemWatcher, (or the relevant API's if not .NET managed), and try to ensure that the only operations performed on the source/target folders are move/rename between folders on the same physical drive, and delete. If you want to add a file, open/write/flush/close it ito a temp folder on the target filesystem drive and only then move/rename it to the folder being watched.  It is vital that the temp folder is on the same physical drive as the target folder so that it can be move/renamed without a data copy.

This works well on non-managed systems, not tried it on C#, but don't see any reason for to not to work OK.

Other solutions involving continual polling and/or checking file sizes are just inconvenient, inflexible, wasteful, messy and latency-ridden at best.

Multithreading - probably yes on any remote filesystem.  Network file calls tend to have very long timeouts on unrechability etc. and so block the caller for what seems like forever before issuing an error/exception.  If you want to get anything else done, you should probably thread off the lot unless your users can tolerate 'hourglass apps', with windows becoming unresponsive, disappearing to back, getting greyed-out and the OS offering to close them.

Oh, and another thing - best to go on a purge when starting up.  Stuff can go wrong at any time, so clean any lingering rubbish from temp folders etc. when running up.

Comment: This has the jist of it, in C#:  http://devproconnections.com/net-framework/how-build-folder-watcher-service-c

Answer (score 5):

> I think I will use `System.Threading.Timer` here to check if a file exists. What do you think of it?

I think you might take a look at the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class which will notify you when the file is created and raise an event instead of you using a Timer that will continuously poll for the existence of the file.

Comment: damn I was posting that exact same thing :p

Comment: This doesn't surprise me as this is the right tool for this job.

Comment: It's funny.  When it gets asked about using `Timer` people say use `FileSystemWatcher`.  When it gets asked about using `FileSystemWatcher`, people say to use `Timer`:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798880/filesystemwatcher-does-not-work-on-files-created-from-windows-service

Answer (score 5):

Timer is very much costly . You can use `FileSystemWatcher` Which Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

```
// Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = /*path*/
    /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
       the renaming of files or directories. */
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
       | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    // Only watch text files.
    watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

    // Add event handlers.
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

    // Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Then this would be the `OnChanged` method:

```
    //This method is called when a file is created, changed, or deleted.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Show that a file has been created, changed, or deleted.
        WatcherChangeTypes wct = e.ChangeType;
        Console.WriteLine("File {0} {1}", e.FullPath, wct.ToString());
    }
```

Reference:  http://devproconnections.com/net-framework/how-build-folder-watcher-service-c

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the FileSystemWatcher it's too flaky

[FileSystemWatcher does not work on files created from windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798880/filesystemwatcher-does-not-work-on-files-created-from-windows-service)

I would use the timer set to a reasonable tick period and you should be ok.

Some sample code

```
Timer_TicK()
{
 // remove tick event handler

 // do your processing

 // add back tick event handler
}
```

This will keep multiple tick events from happening if you have a rather large amount of processing to do.  I wouldn't multi-thread until you find you need to use it due to performance issues.

In C# if you try and read a file while it's being copied by the file system you will get an exception.  You will need to check for that exception or check the properties of the file (size, etc) to know when it's done.

Comment: Thanks Justion.   How do I prevent reading from /writing to a file while my app is using it? In other words, how do I lock it?

Comment: `or check the properties of the file (size, etc) to know when it's done.` I don't understand. Which properties do you mean? As for size, I don't know the size of it exactly.

Comment: Sorry when I say properties I mean File Attributes, http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-attributes/, when you open the file you can specify the mode, you can set it to FileShare.None, FileStream oStream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open,
FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

Comment: Nice.  I could see where getting `DateTime creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\myfile.txt");` periodically would be a lot better than `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: Note, if someone is not using the `System.Windows.Forms Timer`, but the `System.Timers.Timer Timer`, you do not get a `Tick`, but `Elapsed`, and so you need to do `System.Timers.Timer timer1 += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);`.  The function looks like this where you would do your file checking/processing: `protected void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {  if (File.Exists(filePath) { ... }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Full timer example, where I start new threads each time the interval happens (you don't have to, but it is a good practice), which goes and checks if the file is there and reads it and deletes it if it is:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class Service1:  ServiceBase
    {
        Thread syncThread = null;
        System.Timers.Timer timer1;
        string filePath = @"C:\myfile.txt";
        int interval = 60000;  // 1 min -- adjust as necessary

        public Service1()
        {
           InitializeComponent();             
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer1.Interval = interval;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
            timer1.Start();
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            syncThread.Abort();
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        protected void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            syncThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doThread));
            syncThread.Start();
        }
        protected void doThread()
        {
            // whatever you put here, it will
            // run for each timer interval that elapses
            // in a separate thread, and each thread will
            // end when the processing in this function ends

            string fileContent = String.Empty;      

            if (File.Exists(filePath)
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
                fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                fs.Close();
            } 

            if (fileContent != String.Empty)
            {
               // File was present... process the content...

               // Then I do this...
               File.Delete();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I've ran it with no problems.  I prefer to start new threads with each time interval so it doesn't cause issues if the previous run hasn't finished yet.  Going this route, you have that control, can decide what your interval is, and your process is not always going on - just the service.  The other route, with `FileSystemWatcher`, it is always watching and running whenever it can and you cannot adjust your time interval, like you can with a timer, to keep down the number of events/processes going on, such as when/if the file is created, then quickly modified & saved.

Only downside I see is having to check the file attributes yourself, but those are easy enough checks to make.  If you do `File.Delete()` after processing it like I do, you only have `File.Exists(filePath)` to do, in order to find out if the file has been re-created.  If you have to check for modification, you merely check `DateTime lastModifed = File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath)` (see http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-creation-modification-time/ ) against the current time + your interval (which would be `DateTime lastRun = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(interval)`).  If `lastRun > lastModified`, you would have to process it.